# How do I join large set of data that is split into several TCP/IP packets

Tags: c#, .net

My App requests data from a device. All was going well. When the data comes to me I get it as follows.

```
byte[] receiveData = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
int iRx = client.Receive(receiveData);
```

Then I found at times the device sends out lots and lots of data in response to me asking it a question. I can deal with the data except that I only get a certain amount of it. Below we see a Wireshark trace.

IP ending 101 is me and 102 is device. The total amount of data it will return to me for this request is 3975bytes.

I did try above to have the ReceiveBufferSize set to 4000bytes but that did not seem to do anything good or bad.

Looking at the Wireshark I start by requesting data to which I get data returned in two packets 1460bytes and 588bytes then my PC gives it a Ack and the socket forwards a single packet of 2048bytes to the app. Then more data arrives with another 1460 bytes followed by 467bytes. When I give that an ACK I get more data sent to me from the socket this time 1927bytes. Together both packets add up to the correct 3975bytes.

Most commands I send to the device return me between 20 and 120 bytes of data. It is just this one command that returns more.

I would like to get all 3975bytes in one long string so it has the apps header at the front. How do I do that?

I did think that when I send the command I set a flag. If the flag is set the incoming data gets sent to a function and it gets added to until I get all 3975bytes and then I send it on. Without the flag I carry on as now. This seems very messy but maybe it cold work. Any ideas please?

[image: Wireshark Trace]

Comment: Your "flag" idea is the only way to do this, and is in fact the correct general way to approach this regardless of packet size. However, instead of implementing such logic yourself, you might want to consider using a higher-level messaging protocol that essentially does it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it working for the moment I have done the following: On the socket I see I get 4 packets with total data size of 3975bytes. This seems to come to me as 2 sets of 2048bytes.
When I call the command I set the flag.
when I go to the function "decipher_data" I reset the flag and also set full_data to empty string.
full_data and flag are global variables which I do not like and plan to tidy up later when I get more time.
data = the data coming from the socket

```
if (flag) 
{
    full_data += data;
                   
        if (full_data.Length > 2048) 
        {
           decipher_data(full_data);
        }
}
else
{
    //Carry on as before with smaller packets
          decipher_data(data);
}
```

I still wonder how can I tell how much data I am going to get so I can make the value I have of 4096 more flexible?

Comment: This is a daily occurrence in the TCP tag. Why do people keep doing this, why do you want to invent your own protocol? Because you've read TCP is faster than something else, or because it's cool? TCP is a transport protocol, you need an application (framing) protocol on top of that, to indicate message size or message boundaries. Without those, your receiving end has no idea where one message ends and the next one begins.

Comment: Unfortunately we have to use and work with what the customer gives us. Not our choice I am afraid so that is why we run into these problems.